# End line character not working in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

```
public class Bla {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "/sdsaads/gtagrf/eredsa";
    System.out.println(s.replace("a$", ""));

    }
}
```

I want to erase the "a" in the end of the string. When I delete the $, all the "a" disappears, but when I put it, nothing occurs. Explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `replaceAll()` that takes `regular expression` as first parameter.

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("a$", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `replace()` method doesn't expect a regex expression as parameter:

```
String java.lang.String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

You should use `replaceAll()` which expects a regex as parameter:

```
String java.lang.String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

So your code would be:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("a$", ""));
```